# How to Consume a Web Service that requires Login Credentials

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2013

I apologize for my bad English ..

Hi all, I'm having problems when consuming a web service, here's what's happening:

I have a url which exposes the wsdl web service in question, but in order to access the wsdl I have to login, this is the problem I'm having, I am making an application that tries to connect to the webservice but I can not access the wsdl by the login you have, there is some way from programming that can be performed to achieve logearse and reference the webservice later consume ...

I am developing the application in C # Framework 4.5.1.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "login".

Comment: i have to write the user and pass for login to get url  webservice with the wsdl

Answer (score 0):

If your WebService requires you to use Basic Authentication, you will have to pass along a Header in the request named "Authorization", with the content "Basic ".
To make things fun, your Username and Password will have to be sent in the format USERNAME:PASSWORD with Base64 encoding.

It could look as follows:

```csharp
Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Username" + ":" + "Password"));
```

The Header will then look like:

```
Authorization: Basic ddfWt432fDFSDAFDf4FSdf434gfRGHEThF
```